# How can I divide one value by a value in the row before in pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe of 10 observations.  I'd like to divide row 1 by row 2, row 2 by row 3, row 3 by row 4, etc.  When I get to row 10, then I want to divide row 10 by row 1.

Here is some sample code:

```
import pandas as pd
dict1 = {'group':[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
        ,'value': [.35,.41,.40,.60,.36,.55,.49,.57,.57,.52]}
df = pd.DataFrame(dict1)
```

Here is the result I'm looking for:

```
dict1 = {'group':[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
        ,'value': [.35,.41,.40,.60,.36,.55,.49,.57,.57,.52]
        , 'target': [.854,1.025,.667,1.667,.655,1.122,.860,1,1.096,.673]}
df = pd.DataFrame(dict1)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access previous / next elements of a column using *shift*,
but here there is a exception for the last element (divide by the **first** row).

So here you can use *Numpy* function named *roll*, performing "rotation"
or **circular** shift of your column.

To perform your operation, run:

```
df['target'] = df.value / np.roll(df.value, shift=-1)
```